# Private variable is assigned correctly

Tags: c++

**Background**: I do not know C++, I know C.

**Problem**: In a file called `lruTable.hh`, I have defined

```
struct lnode {
    struct lnode *next;
    struct lnode *prev;
};

struct Table {
    struct lnode *list;
    int size;
};

class lruTable {

private:
    struct Table *table;
public:
    lruTable();

};
```

I want the class constructor `lruTable()` to initialize the private variable `table` such that `table->list` is the head of a doubly linked list, and should be initialized to point to itself in both directions. In a file called `lruTable.cc`, I have the constructor as

```
lruTable::lruTable() {
    table = TableAlloc();
}
```

and the table allocator as

```
struct Table *TableAlloc(void) {
    struct Table *t = (struct Table *) malloc(sizeof(struct Table));
    if (t == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: malloc failed\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    t->size = 0;
    t->list = lnconst(); // A
    return t;
}
```

and finally, the lnode allocator as

```
struct lnode *lnconst(void) {

        struct lnode *ln = (struct lnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct lnode *));
        if (ln == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: malloc failed\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ln->next = ln;
        ln->prev = ln;
        return ln;
}
```

I have verified that `lnconst()` initializes list heads like I want it to. In fact, running the GDB, at line A, the Table `t` is exactly as I want it to be with `t->list->next == t->list` and `t->list->prev == t->list`. However, once `TableAlloc()` returns in the constructor, something goes wrong and what I have instead is that `table->list->next == table->list` (desired) and `table->list->prev == table` (incorrect). I have verified this by printing addresses in GDB.

Comment: Are you forced to use `malloc()`  in `c++`?

Comment: I am not. I am reverting to C wherever I can because I don't know C++.

Comment: You should use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`

Comment: Can I expect that something will break if I continue to use `malloc`?

Comment: The best is to use neither `new`/`delete` nor `malloc`/`free`. c++ already has a lot of container classes, including a double linked list.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `struct` when declaring the pointers.  In C++ the `struct` declares a unique type.  So you can state: `lnode * prev; lnode * next;`.

Comment: If you want to learn/use C++, it's not a good idea to "revert to C" whenever you run into something you don't understand.  A lot of good practice in C is poor practice in C++ (and vice versa, where the code carries both ways) so all you'll achieve is becoming a poor programmer who writes in some hybrid of C and C++ that is poor practice in both languages.   It takes more time, but working out how to do things effectively in C++ will mean you're more effective in C++ in the long run.   It also helps to keep track of the differences, if you want to work effectively in both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The followoing line does not allocate the right amount of memory.

```
struct lnode *ln = (struct lnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct lnode *));
```

You need to use

```
struct lnode *ln = (struct lnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
```

Couple of points regarding your code.

1. In C++, you don't need to use `struct Table` and `struct lnode` after they have been declared. You can simply use `Table` and `lnode`.
2. Don't use `malloc`/`free`. Use `new` and `delete`.

Here's what your code can be:

```
struct lnode {
   lnode *next;
   lnode *prev;
};

struct Table {
   lnode *list;
   int size;
};

class lruTable {

   private:
      Table *table;
   public:
      lruTable();

};

lruTable::lruTable() {
    table = TableAlloc();
}

Table *TableAlloc(void) {
    Table* t = new Table;
    t->size = 0;
    t->list = lnconst();
    return t;
}

lnode *lnconst(void) {
   lnode* ln = new lnode;;
   ln->next = ln;
   ln->prev = ln;
   return ln;
}
```

Comment: If you make a proper constructor in `Table`, you don't need `TableAlloc()` you can then do `new Table` directly. Or even better, replace `Table *table` with a smart pointer. Edit: You probably don't need a pointer at all, just do `Table table;`.

Answer (score 3):

Your malloc in `lnconst` is not for enough memory:
`malloc(sizeof(struct lnode *));` will provide size for a pointer, not for a full `struct lnode`.

With that, the memory where you store `prev` is not yours, and it will change whenever it likes (depending on compiler's / OS' memory layout).

Obviously, you need to use `malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));`.

Comment: To add - don't use malloc in C++ unless you absolutely have to. `new` will automatically scale the allocation by the size of the type being constructed, and run the appropriate constructors for those types.

Comment: Can I expect that something will break if I continue to use `malloc`?

Comment: No, if you use it correctly. It's just more dangerous, kind of like driving without a seatbelt.

Comment: Besides being more dangerous the constructor and destructors are not called with malloc() if your struct or class has one.